# import in postgresql 9.5 with pg_read_binary_file

Tags: xml, postgresql, import

I would import file xml into a table.
my file is on the desktop.

`SELECT XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT convert_from(pg_read_binary_file('myfile.xml'), 'UTF8'));`

absolute paths are not allowed

ERR is : no such file or directory.

How to solve?

Comment: Put that file to the server. Then use psql from the same directory...

Comment: how do? @MichałZaborowski

Comment: how change directory?

Comment: You have file at local system - yes? You need it at db. If you have access - you can use scp to tmp, or so, then use ssh to be there and use psql to run your command. There is option to do that from local machine - you can tunnel connection, but that is next level.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp AS
SELECT (xpath('//some_id/text()', x))[1]::text AS id
FROM   unnest(xpath('/xml/path/to/datum', 'myfile.xml')) x;
```